# Bypass a specific user in shibboleth SSO

Tags: apache, jenkins, single-sign-on, reverse-proxy, shibboleth

I have been trying to bypass shibboleth sso for a specific user. Only one user need password authentication to an application running behind Apache reverse proxy. Rest all users need to go through the SSO login.

I tried tweaking few attribute-map files, but in vain.

Any idea on the shibboleth config file to modify for bypassing sso for a single user. Any suggestion on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have code that constructs an "application session" from headers/environment variables within the app, or does the app directly access the existence/absence of the headers/environment variables set by Shibboleth?

If you have an external application session, then you just need to deploy some code to a separate path that's not protected by Shib, but some other means (maybe even Apache Basic Auth), that'll construct the relevant session cookie for the application and do the redirect.

If you're using the existence of the Shibboleth session info directly in the app, then you're probably better off just asking the IdP for an account.

Regardless, you're in the territory of building a back-door... so you must exercise extreme caution to not implement a vulnerability that can be leveraged in some way, and frankly StackOverflow doesn't know the intricacies of your application well enough to give more than general suggestions.

I suppose the short answer is... I don't think you're going to find a short answer.

Comment: The backend app which I was referring is Jenkins. Jenkins is running behind apache reverese proxy and SSO is working perfectly till now. Now we wanted to use python-jenkins api for a user (already enabled API token for the user) and somehow it is failing with unaurthorized error from shibboleth.

Comment: fyi : The api user is not available in ADP